# How to set up Internet access for QEMU?

Tags: linux, networking, qemu

I followed many tutorials online for days and still could not set up internet access for QEMU. I followed [this tutorial](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/setting-up-qemu-with-a-nat/), but it did not work either. Basically the steps are, (copied)

> The simplest approach is to use a NAT. Here are the steps:
>
> As root in the host, create and setup your tap0 device (192.168.100.0
>   will be our NAT network, and felipec our user):
>
> ```
> tunctl -u felipec -t tap0 
> ifconfig tap0 192.168.100.1 up
> ```
>
> Update: You need to run your guest like this:
>
> ```
> qemu-kvm -hda winxp.cow -m 512 -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no
> ```
>
> In your guest:
>                 `ip addr: 192.168.100.2`
>                 `gateway: 192.168.100.1`
>                 `dns: 8.8.8.8`
>
> **note:** I found some problems on my Windows XP guest; I had to disable
>   the firewall
>   **note:** I’m using Google’s DNS, if you want to use the one
>   in your host check */etc/resolv.conf*
>
> **NAT**
>
> As root in the host:
>
> ```
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
> iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o tap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```
>
> That’s it. Now you should be able to use ping back-and-forth between
>   the guest and the host, and both should be able to access the Internet

When I follow these steps, tap0 interface does not appear in guest's `ifconfig` (I'm running ubuntu on both guest and host). And I'm not able to `ping` guest from host or vice versa. Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Where does -hda winxp.cow come into play In This?